# SQL script, how can i execute the following script?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-scripts

I have to execute this script . The problem in that in SQL Developer i cant run it,since some operators are not recognized .

```
P_jobgroup_id :
'GDWH2MYGDWH-GDWH2MYGDWH'           CORE load finished
'GDWH2MYGDWH-GDWH2MYGDWH_IF'        IF finished
'GDWH2MYGDWH-GDWH2MYGDWH_INIT'  IF or CORE started

declare
 p_context_code          varchar2(100) := 'GDWH2MYGDWH';
 v_res                   varchar2(100);
begin
v_res := OJC.jc_master.main 
     (
      p_batch_number => NULL,
      p_jobgroup_id => 'GDWH2MYGDWH-GDWH2MYGDWH'),
      p_parameters_string => 'GDWH2MYGDWH.PRM_REPORTING_DATE='||to_char(sysdate,'yyyymmddhh24miss',
      p_context_code =>p_context_code
     );
end;
/
```

> Error starting at line 1 in command: P_jobgroup_id : Error report:
>   Unknown Command
>
> Error starting at line 2 in command: 'GDWH2MYGDWH-GDWH2MYGDWH'
>         CORE load finished Error report: Unknown Command ORA-06550: line 8,
>   column 50: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "," when expecting one of
>   the following:
>
> . ( * % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem

Comment: What should the part before the `declare` do?

Comment: those are declarations related to the status of the release (gdwh2mygdwh) so if the Interface started(IF ) it should  edit the table data to GDWH2MYGDWH-GDWH2MYGDWH_INIT. 

The main problem is how to run from declare and below. thanks

Comment: Comment that part before DECLARE; it is invalid in this context, I'm afraid.

Comment: The whole part before the DECLARE is invalid in PL/SQL - what do you expect that to do? Where in the [manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/toc.htm) did you find that syntax?

Comment: ok but how can i run the code after declare ? cause i can try removing that part of the code ,and see what is going to happen ... But still there are lot of other syntacts error such as => .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first par of the script is not valid PLSQL code.
Commenting or removing it will make the script run, once fixed a couple of syntax errors.

```
/*
    P_jobgroup_id :
    'GDWH2MYGDWH-GDWH2MYGDWH'           CORE load finished
    'GDWH2MYGDWH-GDWH2MYGDWH_IF'        IF finished
    'GDWH2MYGDWH-GDWH2MYGDWH_INIT'  IF or CORE started
 */
DECLARE
    p_context_code                          VARCHAR2(100) := 'GDWH2MYGDWH';
    v_res                                   VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    v_res := OJC.jc_master.main
        (
         p_batch_number         => NULL,
         p_jobgroup_id          => 'GDWH2MYGDWH-GDWH2MYGDWH',
         p_parameters_string    => 'GDWH2MYGDWH.PRM_REPORTING_DATE=' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'yyyymmddhh24miss'),
         p_context_code         => p_context_code
        );
END;
/
```